# When I connect the sql, the interface of Jframe won't show

Tags: java, mysql

[image]
[image]

This is my sql connection code

```
public class sqlconn {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection connectionDB(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/java", "root"," ");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Database connected");

            return conn;

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Database connect failed");
              return null;
    }


}
}
```

Jframe code

```
public class register extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    /**
     * Creates new form register
     */
    public register() {
        initComponents();
        conn = sqlconn.connectionDB();
    }
```

Jframe button

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
            String id = IDtxt.getText().toString();
            String password = PASStxt.getText().toString();
            String phone = PHONEtxt.getText().toString();
            String email = MAILtxt.getText().toString();

            String role = (String)cmbROLE.getSelectedItem();
        try{
            String query="insert into users(username,password,email,phone_num,role) values(id,password,phone,email,role)";
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

[image]

The program is running but no Jframe shows once I add the sql query into the Jframe. I am using wamp server as my database.

Once I run for awhile the error is "Database connect failed".

Comment: `The program is running but no Jframe show once i add the sql query into the Jframe` - the SQL query needs to execute on a separate Thread so you don't prevent the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) from repainting the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Based on your message and your code you didn't even get connected to the database, so I ask, is your database password really a single blank space? `....localhost:8080/java", "root"," ");` <<<<< here It's most probably that it is an empty password therefore it should be `localhost:8080/java", "root","");`

Comment: @JorgeCampos i change to Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/java", "root",""); the result is the same please help

Comment: Two questions, is your MySQL running? Do you have a database named java on it?

Comment: OOOOOOooooooh just realized what it is wrong. MySql when installed run on port 3306 so your connection is wrongly using the port 8080 which is usually for container servers like Apache Tomcat. So change it to `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root","");` and let me know so I can add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just that you are using the wrong port and password to connect to MySQL here:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/java", 
                                              "root",
                                              " ");
```

MySQL default installations uses the user `root` with an empty password `""` and it is also installed at the port `3306`, `8080` is the default port to Application containers such as Apache Tomcat, Apache HTTP, JBoss, etc. So you should change your connection string to:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", 
                                              "root",
                                              "");
```